# Responding to a routed command in a viewmodel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to handle a routed command from a button, in my viewmodel. I can get it working in the Usercontrol's codebehind as follows:

```
Dim NewCommandBinding As CommandBinding = New CommandBinding(GlobalCommands.ResultsFilterChangedCommand,
                                                                     AddressOf ExecuteResultsFilterChanged,
                                                                     AddressOf CanExecuteResultsFilterChanged)
        CommandBindings.Add(NewCommandBinding)
```

And then bind to it in XAML:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="FilterTgl" Content="Archives" Margin="10,4" Padding="10,2"
                            Command="cmds:GlobalCommands.ResultsFilterChangedCommand" />
```

But when I move the code to the viewmodel, I get 'Commandbindings is not declared'. Presumably because my UserControl is UI and my ViewModel is not.

Should I not be trying to handle a command directly in my viewmodel? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MVVM, I would *strongly* recommend that you investigate the `RelayCommand`. This is absolutely perfect for MVVM as it enables you to write commands with a simple Lambda expression. Here is a simple example using my custom `ActionCommand` which is very similar to the `RelayCommand`:

```
public override ICommand DeleteCommand
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action => Delete(action), canExecute => CanDelete()); }
}
```

You can find a detailed description of the `RelayCommand` in the [*WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) article on MSDN and a clearer implementation of it in the [*Implementation RelayCommand*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d44932d3-ba6a-4ca1-88e0-c34665123a5c/implementation-relaycommand?forum=wpf) post on the MSDN Developer Forum.

Comment: True, however with the `RelayCommand` you lose the routing capbility of a `RoutedCommand`. Thus making focus dependend behavior of a GUI harder to do.

Comment: *making focus dependend behavior of a GUI harder to do*... I'm really not sure what that means, but I don't have any focusing problems in my applications.

Comment: Just to clarify: You could have a Menubar as "Edit-Copy" which triggers the global ApplicationCommands.Copy - command. You could then have 3 list boxes and 2 text fields in your GUI. Dependent on your focussed element, copy will trigger a copy method on either of the gui elements. This is the feature of RoutedCommands

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your viewmodel should be handling the button press by declaring a command property that your xaml binds to - see this link for a simple example:  [MWWV Command Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute)

Answer (score 2):

You should databind to your command instead of setting the property explicitly.  Assuming that your ViewModel is your view's data context, the syntax would look something like this (I haven't tried to run this):

```
<ToggleButton Command="{Binding NameOfTheCommandPropertyOnYourViewModel}"/>
```

Your viewmodel should expose your command as an ICommand, and it should be a property (not just a field).

I also agree with Sheridan -- you should really consider a relay command.